# NSTimer обратный отсчет

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Вспм привет! Подскажите, как решить задачу. Есть 3 pickerView: количество повторений, время работы, время отдыха. Нужно сделать таймер. Обратный отсчет и отображенип в label сделал. Не могу начать отсчет с выбранного значения и остановить когда 0 и начать отчет от второго выбранного значения и уменьшить количество повторов на 1. В принципе с количестве повторов я понимаю что можно сделать в цикле. Но вот с отчета с заданного значения пока разобраться не могу.

Comment: опубликуй свой код, а я уже его подправлю

Comment: @Igor весь класс скинуть?

Comment: как считаешь нужным, нужна инициализация, обработка тика и вывод

Comment: @Igor не могу сюда вставить, не влезает(( если попробую на гит хаб кинуть норм?

Comment: конечно, кидай, можешь тогда уже весь проект закинуть

Comment: @Igor что то не получилось кинуть на гит вот сюда кинул https://yadi.sk/d/BnBGAx2Om5zZ7. попробую позже на гит добавить

Comment: даже видя ваш код не понимаю что вы хотите сделать. ни одной переменной связанной с работой таймеров не нашел :(

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko честно говоря, в том-то и вопрос, я понимаю что нужно сделать 3 переменные под каждый пикер. В одном уменьшать количество на 1 по истечению время, в другие 2 передавать данные из пикера и от заданного значения начинать отсчет. Хочу попросить совет как это можно написать, возможно посмотреть где подобное реализовано.

Comment: давайте еще раз: допустим три пикера. я ставлю 5 в первом, 5 во втором, 5 в третьем. что должно произойти?

Comment: В каждую переменную записывается это значение и начинается отсчет от переменный timeWork, как стало 0 переменная round уменьшить на 1 и включилсч второй таймер timeRest. После того как timeRest 0 сразу включается timeWork. Как timeWork 0, уменьшается round на 1 и опять timeRest. Так до тех пор пока round и timeWork не станет 0, как 0 все, конец программы.

Comment: привет, добрался до твоего кода, если еще актуально, постучись в скайп igor_dnp разберемся..

Comment: @Igor привет, хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko подскажи, пожалуйста, правильно я размышляю? где можно поискать инфу на эту тему, я просто никак найти не могу(

Comment: я был уверен, что вам уже помогли с этим вопросом

Comment: вам надо несколько переменных - 3 для хранения значений введенных в picker, одна для обратного отсчета и одна для указания, какой обратный отсчет сейчас происходит - работа или отдых. когда нажата кнопка присваиваете 3 значения из пикеров соответствующим переменным, присваиваете переменной обратного отсчета значение из время работы, присваиваете переменной обозначающей тип действия "работа" и начинаете отсчет. когда отсчет закончился присваиваете "отдых", присваиваете обратному отсчету значение из время отдыха и начинаете новый отсчет. когда он закончился уменьшаете количество повторений.

Comment: когда осталось 0 повторений заканчиваете процесс.

Comment: можно попросить в виде кода показать на примере одной переменой.    `NSMutableArray *mutableArrayTimeRest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    for (int min = 0; min < 6; min++)
        for (int sec = 0; sec < 60; sec++)
        {
            
            [mutableArrayTimeRest addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d",min, sec]];
        }
    self.timeRest = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArrayTimeRest];` как это записать в переменную?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko подскажи пожалуйста, не могу разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то типа такого

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MSWeakTimer.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIPickerView) NSArray *pickerView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeWorkText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeRestText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *roundText;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray * rounds;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray * timeWork;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray * timeRest;


@property (strong, nonatomic) MSWeakTimer *timer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MSWeakTimer *backgroundTimer;

@property (strong, nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t privateQueue;

@property (nonatomic) int roundsCount;
@property (nonatomic) int timeWorkCount;
@property (nonatomic) int timeRestCount;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isWorking;
@property (nonatomic) int countDown;

@end


@implementation ViewController

static const char *MSSampleViewControllerTimerQueueContext = "MSSampleViewControllerTimerQueueContext";

@synthesize
pickerView = _pickerView;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.privateQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mindsnacks.private_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

        self.backgroundTimer = [MSWeakTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                                    target:self
                                                                  selector:@selector(backgroundTimerDidFire)
                                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                                   repeats:YES
                                                             dispatchQueue:self.privateQueue];

        dispatch_queue_set_specific(self.privateQueue, (__bridge const void *)(self), (void *)MSSampleViewControllerTimerQueueContext, NULL);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_timer invalidate];
    [_backgroundTimer invalidate];
}




- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.roundsCount = 1;

    //rounds
    NSMutableArray *mutableArrayRounds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int rounds = 1; rounds < 16; rounds++) {

        [mutableArrayRounds addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rounds]];
    }
    self.rounds = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArrayRounds];

    //TimeRest

    NSMutableArray *mutableArrayTimeRest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int min = 0; min < 6; min++)
        for (int sec = 0; sec < 60; sec++)
        {

            [mutableArrayTimeRest addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d",min, sec]];
        }
    self.timeRest = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArrayTimeRest];


    //TimeWork

    NSMutableArray *mutableArrayTimeWork = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int min = 0; min < 6; min++)
        for (int sec = 0; sec < 60; sec++)
        {

            [mutableArrayTimeWork addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d", min, sec]];
        }
    self.timeWork = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArrayTimeWork];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSInteger title = 0;

    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        title = [self.rounds count];
    }
    if (pickerView.tag == 2) {
        title =[self.timeRest count];
    }
    if (pickerView.tag == 3) {
        title =[self.timeWork count];

    }

    return title;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString * titleRow;

    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        titleRow = [self.rounds objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (pickerView.tag == 2) {
        titleRow = [self.timeRest objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (pickerView.tag == 3) {
        titleRow = [self.timeWork objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    return titleRow;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        self.roundsCount = [[self.rounds objectAtIndex:row] integerValue];
    }
    if (pickerView.tag == 2) {
        self.timeWorkCount = [self convertTime:[self.timeRest objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
    if (pickerView.tag == 3) {
        self.timeRestCount = [self convertTime:[self.timeWork objectAtIndex:row] ];
    }

}


#pragma mark actions


- (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.roundText.text = 0;
    self.timeWorkText.text = 0;
    self.timeRestText.text = 0;

}

- (IBAction)goButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    {
        static NSString *kStopTimerText = @"Stop";
        static NSString *kStartTimerText = @"Start";

        NSString *currentTitle = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];

        if ([currentTitle isEqualToString:kStopTimerText])
        {
            [sender setTitle:kStartTimerText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.timer invalidate];
        }
        else
        {
            self.roundText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.roundsCount];
            self.isWorking = YES;
            self.countDown = self.timeWorkCount;

            [sender setTitle:kStopTimerText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.timer = [MSWeakTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                              target:self
                                                            selector:@selector(mainThreadTimerDidFire:)
                                                            userInfo:nil
                                                             repeats:YES
                                                       dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        }

    }

}

- (int)convertTime:(NSString*)time
{
    NSLog(@"time %@", time);
    long minutes = [[time substringToIndex:1] integerValue];
    long seconds = [[time substringFromIndex:3] integerValue];
    return minutes*60+seconds;
}

#pragma mark - mainThreadTimer

- (void)mainThreadTimerDidFire:(MSWeakTimer *)timer
{
    NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"This should be called from the main thread");

    self.countDown--;

    if(self.isWorking) {
        self.timeWorkText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.countDown];
    } else {
        self.timeRestText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.countDown];
    }

    if(self.countDown <= 0) {
        if(self.isWorking) {
            self.isWorking = NO;
            self.countDown = self.timeRestCount;
        } else {
            self.roundsCount--;
            self.roundText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.roundsCount];
            if(self.roundsCount <= 0) {
                [self.timer invalidate];
                return;
            }
            self.isWorking = YES;
            self.countDown = self.timeWorkCount;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark backgroundTimer

- (void)backgroundTimerDidFire
{
    NSAssert(![NSThread isMainThread], @"This shouldn't be called from the main thread");

    const BOOL calledInPrivateQueue = dispatch_queue_get_specific(self.privateQueue, (__bridge const void *)(self)) == MSSampleViewControllerTimerQueueContext;
    NSAssert(calledInPrivateQueue, @"This should be called on the provided queue");
}


@end
```

Comment: таймер почему-то отказывается работать и ругается на `return minutes*60+seconds;`

Comment: какая именно ошибка?

Comment: implicit conversion loses integer precision 'long' to 'int'

Comment: это ж не ошибка, это warning

Comment: Ну это да, так-то все работает. Но таймер почему-то не считает. Просто делает -1 при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: вы весь код скопировали?

Comment: а что такое "таймер не считает"?

Comment: не знаю как так, но щас все получилось, единственное он не распознает минуты, то есть если выбрать 1:05 он записывает 65. с одной стороны математически правильно, но не оч красиво...

Comment: ну я думаю это вы сможете исправить

Comment: Ну да, посижу, подумаю. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: а можешь, пожалуйста, поподробней рассказать, что делает `- (int)convertTime:(NSString*)time
{
    NSLog(@"time %@", time);
    long minutes = [[time substringToIndex:1] integerValue];
    long seconds = [[time substringFromIndex:3] integerValue];
    return minutes * 60 + seconds;
}` я немного не понял.

Comment: @DavidKakaladze у вас время представлено в виде строки, например "1 : 30", то есть, чтоб из этого дела получить минуты, надо отрезать первый символ (substringToIndex:1) и сконвертировать в integer. Потом, чтобы получить секунды надо отрезать все символы после 3го (1[пробел][двоеточие][пробел]) и тоже сконвертировать в integer. Потом умножить минуты на 60 и пробавить секунды, чтобы получить окончательное премя в секундах. Кстати, если будет 10 или больше минут, это все работать перестанет :)

Comment: подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю что для того чтобы мне сделать отображение в `Label` не 65 секунд, а 1:05, мне нужно конвертировать по тому же принципу?